# Shiny : make a functional app integrable as an iframe

Tags: r, shiny

I want to write, inside a package I've uploaded on the cran, a shiny extension that takes an object and allows various operations. Hence, the app is a functional one, this type :

```
ui <- function(x) fluidPage(
    titlePanel(paste("displaying", x, "*m")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("m",
                        "m:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),
        mainPanel(textOutput("product"))
    )
)
server <- function(x) {
    function(input, output) {
        output$product <- renderText(as.character(x*input$m))
    }
}
run_app <- function(x) runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui(x), server = server(x)))
run_app(4)
```

(I've copied the style i've seen inside the wonderful **vdiffr** package)

It has a beautiful readability. However, there is a limitation with this functional writing : as far as I know it can't run as a standalone app, hence it can't be deployed and integrated as an iframe (I'd like to be able, outside my package uploaded to the cran, to be able to integrate it inside a bigger shinydashboard at my company without having to copy/paste/modify the code).

Is there a fine way to reconciliate both views, ie some *fine* way to write shiny functions that can also run as standalones (where you would be able to modify the functional input from inside the bigger app) ?

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't it be possible to view a shiny app provided as a function in an iframe?

Here is a simple single file example using `callr` to spawn another R session for the inner app. Depending on how you host your apps this might not be necessary - all you need is the URL of the inner app.

```
library(shiny)
library(callr)

callr::r_bg(function(myArg) {
  
  library(shiny)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    p(paste("inner app:", myArg)),
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {}
  
  app <- shinyApp(ui, server)
  
  runApp(app, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080)
  
}, args = list(myArg = 4), supervise = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  p("outer app"),
  tags$iframe(src="http://127.0.0.1:8080", scrolling="yes") # , height="900vh", width="100%", frameborder="0"
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Furthermore, you might want to look into [shiny modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, r_bg could be part of the solution
However, the point of having a functional app would be to call it with an arg that comes from within the global app, ie something like :

`server_global <- function(input, output, session) observe(callr::r_bg(run_app, args = list(x = input$x), supervise = TRUE))`
I can't make it work that way, it seems like callr isn't fine with reactive values. (btw I KNOW my code would be neither effective nor beautiful even if it worked)

Comment: `callr` is just a way to spawn two shiny apps from a single file to show that the iframe is working fine - as mentioned above you don't need it, you can spawn two R sessions and realize the same. Or is your question rather, how to pass reactives from one shiny app to another?

Comment: that's the question. Maybe the separation between 2 apps is wrong and I should try a module which depends of reactive values that comes either from a r object (if the module is called via a function) or from a superior shiny app (if the module is called via an app).

Comment: Yep, sounds like you are looking for modules. Communication between two shiny apps is possible for sure, but would require [interprocess communication](https://github.com/fellstat/ipc) combined with the above iframe approach it seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Nevertheless, did the above answer your initial question?